# Multiple parameters on jquery ajax call asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to pass two parameters on an ajax call. I already tried several ways suggested on StakeOverflow but none worked. Here is my method signature on controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase[] files, string[] usersToShare)
```

Here is my function:

```
function uploadFile() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("files").files.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            var file = document.getElementById("files").files[i];
            formData.append("files", file);
        }

        //get the selected usernames (email) to share the file
        var selectedUsers = [];
        $("#costumerUsersListSelect :selected").each(function () {
            selectedUsers.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/ManageFiles/UploadFile', 
            data: "files=" + formData + "usersToShare=" + selectedUsers,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {                    
            },
            error: function (error) {                  
            }
        });
    }
```

So I want to pass to the controller the **formData** and the **selectedUsers**. If I pass just the formData (Data: formData) everything works but I need to pass the selectedUsers too.

Here what I already tried without any success:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ files: formData, usersToShare: selectedUsers }),
data: { files: formData, usersToShare: JSON.stringify(selectedUsers)},
data: "files=" + formData + "&usersToShare=" + selectedUsers,
data: "files=" + formData + "usersToShare=" + selectedUsers,
```

I am not sure if this is a syntax issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: into your code behind  into model folder create a object to request and use its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
data: "files=" + formData + "usersToShare=" + selectedUsers,
```

append the `selectedUsers` in `formData` and send only `formData` to the server like:

```
data: formData,
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different keys for each value you append to formData, and then just append both files and users the same way

```
function uploadFile() {
  var formData   = new FormData();
  var allFiles   = $("#files").get(0).files;

  for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
    formData.append("files_" + i, allFiles[i]);
  }

  $("#costumerUsersListSelect :selected").each(function(_,i) {
    formData.append('user_' + i, this.value);
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/ManageFiles/UploadFile',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(error) {}
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax:

`data: JSON.stringify(obj);`

before your ajax statement, define your parameters like:

`var obj = { files: formData , usersToShare: selectedUsers };`