# How To Pass a file and a string via an ajax call to the controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a file and a string to the controller. When submit button is pressed the file chosen and a string are sent to the controller and automatic model binder works for the file but not for the string.This is what i have done till now. Thank you!

```
<div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
            <div>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="someFile" />
                <button id="but_upload"> submit</button>
           </div>
        </form>
 </div>

 <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#but_upload").click(function () {

            var myFile = $('#file').prop('files');
            var data = {
                someFile:myFile,
                myString: "Hello World"
            };
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'html',

                type: 'POST',

                url: '/Home/PassFileAndData',

                data: data,

                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                },

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
    public ActionResult PassFileAndData(HttpPostedFileBase someFile , string myString)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I Also Found this post :
[Multiple parameters on jquery ajax call asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997194/multiple-parameters-on-jquery-ajax-call-asp-net) and instead the above javascript code i tried this. but again only the file is passed to the controller. Any help pls?

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#but_upload").click(function () {


            var myFile = $('#file').prop('files');
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("someFile", myFile);
            formData.append("myString","HelloWorld");
            $.ajax({

                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //if i want automatic model binding vgale ta sxolia
                //enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                //cache: false,
                dataType: 'html',

                type: 'POST',

                url: '/Home/PassFileAndData',

                data: formData,

                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success passing List");
                },

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Your ActionResult takes a file and a string as method parameters. Try instead creating a model(class) that contains a file and string. The data object that you're are posting is one object with two properties. Therefore your ActionResult needs to take one object with two properties.

Comment: you can not pass file as well as string parallel,  you need to make two calls for it

Comment: JKERNY: i  tried it and nothing the same problem again

Comment: Vishal modi : what do you mean make two calls, how am i going to get the results together in the controller???